# Why was the resource-recommendation tag removed from my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, resource-recommendation

[In my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/755524/237923) I ask for a reference that presents the recursive calculation of the HaMiDeW coefficients. The resource-recommendation tag seemed perfectly suitable to me, but both the tag and my request were removed by another user. In addition, I think that the intent of my post is not clear anymore. What do you think? Is the edit legitimate? If yes, can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 4):

Res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE. They usually cannot be combined with other questions in the same post, but should be asked separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining your reasoning. I don't quite understand yet: What "other questions" did I ask?

Comment: That would be the implicit question in the last sentence (v6): _I think that even the computation of $[a_2]$ is very laborious and I am hoping that someone bothered to present it in some detail._

Comment: Okay, maybe I should have said that the computation **is** laborious, since I am very confident that this is the case. And hence I do not expect that someone will present the calculation in an answer. That's why I thought that it is better to ask for references.

Comment: Ok, in that case, try to reformulate it as a pure res. recom. q.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback.